# Prove there exists a measurable subset $E' \subset E$ such that $f$ is almost everywhere of one sign on $E'$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f \in L\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ where $L$ denotes Lebesgue integrable space of functions. Suppose there exists a subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $m(E) > 0$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in E$. Prove there exists a measurable subset $E' \subset E$ such $m(E') > 0$ and $f$ is almost everywhere of one sign on $E'$.

---

My (weak) attempt:

Let $E_\alpha = \{E \setminus A: m(E) = m(E \setminus A)\}$.... I don't know. Rewrote this proof like 10 times with no insight. So now I'm just throwing it out there. Thank you.

---

I think all I need is a hint to start it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: take $P = \{f > 0\}$ and $N= \{f < 0\}$. Now,

$$
E = (E \cap P) \sqcup (E \cap N).
$$

Certainly $f$ maintains its sign in each of these. Can they both be of measure zero?

Comment: Ah, thank you. But is it easy to show these two sets are measurable?

Comment: Yes, intersection of measurable sets is measurable and $f \in L(\mathbb{R})$ implies measurability. Hence both level sets are measurable.

Comment: So if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, then its level sets are always measurable? What is that theorem called, or do you possibly have a link?

Comment: You can find surely find it on Zygmund's Measure and Integral. I can give you a sketch of the proof: in the book it is proven (in the chapter on Fubini's theorem) that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n_1 + n_2}$ is measurable, then $E^y := \{x : (x,y) \in E \}$ is measurable a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2}$. Since the integral can be define as the measure of the set under the graphic of $f$, the fact that $f$ is integrable tells us that this set $R(f,E)$ is measurable and so $R(f,E)^y = \{ f > y\}$ is measurable a.e. $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (cont.) Since the set where the level sets are _not_ measureable is of measure zero, the set where they _are_ measurable must be dense, and so $f$ is measurable (this last result is also proved in the same book).